# Python JSON reader and parser not filtering results

Tags: python, json

I am trying to filter out specific results from the JSON file that is in one directory called "jsonfiles". This is my code:

```
import json

jsonFileN = open('jsonfiles\galaxy1.json', 'r', encoding="utf8")
jsonData = jsonFileN.read()

obj = json.loads(jsonData)
planets = [i for i in jsonData['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]
print(planets)
```

However, I do get the following error everytime I run the program in my PyCharm and I do not know why:

```
line 22, in <module>
    planets = [i for i in jsonData['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Here is some of the content of my JSON file that I have tried to read and go through:

```
{
  "collection": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "href": "http://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=galaxy&page=1",
    "items": [
      {
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04921/collection.json",
        "data": [
          {
            "center": "JPL",
            "title": "Andromeda Galaxy",
            "nasa_id": "PIA04921",
            "media_type": "image",
            "keywords": [
              "Galaxy Evolution Explorer GALEX"
            ],
            "date_created": "2003-12-10T22:41:32Z",
            "description_508": "This image is from NASA Galaxy Evolution Explorer is an observation of the large galaxy in Andromeda, Messier 31. The Andromeda galaxy is the most massive in the local group of galaxies that includes our Milky Way.",
            "secondary_creator": "NASA/JPL/California Institute of Technology",
            "description": "This image is from NASA Galaxy Evolution Explorer is an observation of the large galaxy in Andromeda, Messier 31. The Andromeda galaxy is the most massive in the local group of galaxies that includes our Milky Way."
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          {
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04921/PIA04921~thumb.jpg",
            "rel": "preview",
            "render": "image"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04634/collection.json",
        "data": [
          {
            "center": "JPL",
            "title": "Galaxy NGC5474",
            "nasa_id": "PIA04634",
            "media_type": "image",
            "keywords": [
              "Galaxy Evolution Explorer GALEX",
              "NGC5474"
            ],
            "date_created": "2003-07-25T16:20:14Z",
            "description_508": "NASA Galaxy Evolution Explorer took this ultraviolet color image of the galaxy NGC5474 on June 7, 2003. NGC5474 is located 20 million light-years from Earth and is within a group of galaxies dominated by the Messier 101 galaxy.",
            "secondary_creator": "NASA/JPL/Caltech",
            "description": "NASA Galaxy Evolution Explorer took this ultraviolet color image of the galaxy NGC5474 on June 7, 2003. NGC5474 is located 20 million light-years from Earth and is within a group of galaxies dominated by the Messier 101 galaxy. Star formation in this galaxy shows some evidence of a disturbed spiral pattern, which may have been induced by tidal interactions with Messier 101.  http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA04634"
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          {
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04634/PIA04634~thumb.jpg",
            "rel": "preview",
            "render": "image"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your json?

Comment: Try to change the line 
planets = [i for i in jsonData['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]
to
planets = [i for i in obj['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]

Answer (score 0):

A couple things -

1. You are loading your json into `obj` but then you are trying to parse your `jsonData` object.
2. If you use `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()` you can get a dict obj from your json file like so:

   ```
    import json

    with open('galaxy.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
        obj = json.load(jsonFile)
    planets = [i for i in obj['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]
    print(planets)
   ```